# How can this query violate primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Suppose I have an empty `ProductLocalizations` table, with a composite primary key made up by the `ProductId` and `LanguageCode` fields, and I execute the following query.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ProductLocalizations (ProductId, LanguageCode, Name, Description) 
SELECT ProductId, LanguageCode1, Name1, Description1 FROM dbo.BulkProducts 
WHERE ProductId NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM dbo.ProductLocalizations) UNION 
SELECT ProductId, LanguageCode2, Name2, Description2 FROM dbo.BulkProducts
WHERE ProductId NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM dbo.ProductLocalizations) UNION 
SELECT ProductId, LanguageCode3, Name3, Description3 FROM dbo.BulkProducts
WHERE ProductId NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM dbo.ProductLocalizations) UNION 
SELECT ProductId, LanguageCode4, Name4, Description4 FROM dbo.BulkProducts
WHERE ProductId NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM dbo.ProductLocalizations)
```

From my (limited) SQL knowledge, since the query contains the

`WHERE ProductId NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM dbo.ProductLocalizations)`

clause, there shouldn't be any way to insert a duplicate (invalid) record. However, when executing this I receive

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK_dbo.ProductLocalizations'. Cannot insert duplicate key
>   in object 'dbo.ProductLocalizations'. The duplicate key value is
>   (29977, de). The statement has been terminated.

What am I missing?

Comment: What if `BulkProducts` and `BulkProdu` having common `ProductId` ex:100 which is not present in `ProductLocalizations` table.

Comment: Also it looks like you have **composite Primary key** in `ProductLocalizations` table so you need to check `ProductId + another column` existence

Comment: check that the `LanguageCode1` is not the same as `LanguageCode2` or others for the same `ProductId`

Comment: @Prdp `BulkProdu` is actually `BulkProducts`, sorry for the typo. @Squirrel checked, I only have a few records in my `BulkProducts` table, and they're clearly not the same.

Comment: i mean that is one possiblity also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a composite Primary Key in your table which is composed of `ProductId` and `LanguageCode`. You need to modify your `WHERE` clause to use `NOT EXISTS`. Additionally, [seeing as you're unpivoting the table, you may want to use `CROSS APPLY` to improve the speed](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CROSS+APPLY+VALUES+UNPIVOT/91234/):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ProductLocalizations (ProductId, LanguageCode, Name, Description) 
SELECT
    bp.ProductId, t.LanguageCode, t.Name, t.Description
FROM dbo.BulkProducts bp
CROSS APPLY(
    VALUES  (LanguageCode1, Name1, Description1),
            (LanguageCode2, Name2, Description2),
            (LanguageCode3, Name3, Description3),
            (LanguageCode4, Name4, Description4)
) t(LanguageCode, Name, Description)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.ProductLocalizations p
    WHERE
        p.ProductId = bp.ProductId
        AND p.LanguageCode = t.LanguageCode
)
```

---

If you can't use `CROSS APPLY`, here is the improved `UNION ALL` version:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ProductLocalizations (ProductId, LanguageCode, Name, Description) 
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT ProductId, LanguageCode1, Name1, Description1 FROM dbo.BulkProducts bp UNION ALL
    SELECT ProductId, LanguageCode2, Name2, Description2 FROM dbo.BulkProducts bp UNION ALL
    SELECT ProductId, LanguageCode3, Name3, Description3 FROM dbo.BulkProducts bp UNION ALL
    SELECT ProductId, LanguageCode4, Name4, Description4 FROM dbo.BulkProducts bp 
) t (ProductId, LanguageCode, Name, Description)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.ProductLocalizations p
    WHERE
        p.ProductId = t.ProductId
        AND p.LanguageCode = t.LanguageCode
)
```

Comment: Thank you. In what circumstances could I not use `CROSS APPLY`?

Comment: @iuliu.net, if you're using an older version of SQL Server. If I'm not mistaken, `APPLY` became available in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ProductId, LanguageCode1, Name1, Description1 FROM dbo.BulkProducts 
WHERE ProductId NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM dbo.ProductLocalizations) UNION 
SELECT ProductId, LanguageCode2, Name2, Description2 FROM dbo.BulkProdu
WHERE ProductId NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM dbo.ProductLocalizations) UNION 
SELECT ProductId, LanguageCode3, Name3, Description3 FROM dbo.BulkProdu
WHERE ProductId NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM dbo.ProductLocalizations) UNION 
SELECT ProductId, LanguageCode4, Name4, Description4 FROM dbo.BulkProdu
WHERE ProductId NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM dbo.ProductLocalizations)
```

Your select queries are returning duplicate values for productID and languagecode columns

Comment: It might be worth clarifying that the queries aren't returning *entirely* duplicated rows, since otherwise `UNION` is broken - but they *are* duplicates when only considering the `ProductId` and `LanguageCode` columns.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever modified my answer. Thanks for your suggestion.